# How to add a new sheet to data table during run time and insert some data into the same using QTP

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I have added a new data sheet to the data table during run time. Now my requirement is, I want to access the newly added data sheet and insert some data into the same sheet.
**Approach Followed:**
1.Added a sheet called 'Srinu' during run time with the statement

`DataTable.AddSheet("Srinu")`

2.Later accessed the first row of the newly added sheet with the statement

```
DataTable.GetSheet("Srinu").SetCurrentRow(1)
```

3.Now tried inserting data in the column 'A'using the statement

```
DataTable.Value("A",dtLocalSheet)=10
```

**Got the below error:**

> The set DataTable.Vale operation failed. The 'A' column does not exist

Answer (score 2):

Use the addParameter method:

```
DataTable.AddSheet("Srinu")
DataTable.GetSheet("Srinu").AddParameter "column_Name1","value1"
DataTable.GetSheet("Srinu").AddParameter "column_Name2","value2"
```

Also, the sheet added during the run-time will only be available for use during the run time. Once your script has executed, you will not be able to access it until you run your code again.

But you can still have a look at your run-time datasheet from the Last Run Results report as evident from the following screenshot:

[image]

For more help on addParameter method, click [Here](http://helpfiles.intactcloud.com/QTP/11.00/QTP11-00_GeneralHelp/Utility/Parameterization_DTSheet_AddParameter.htm).

Let me know if it resolves your issue.

Comment: It didn't resolve my issue but i got the solution.
Thanks Kira

Answer (score 0):

Use `DataTable.Value("A","Srinu")=10` to insert data into the specifically added worksheet.

`dtLocalSheet` usually refers to the sheet associated with the action and usually named `Action1` (or whatever the action name is).  Data in this sheet is only accessible from the specific action that "owns" it.

`dtGlobalSheet` refers to the datatable worksheet Global which contains data accessible by the entire script (all actions).

You have inserted a new sheet called "Srinu" and so to interact with it, you need to specify it by name.

Currently you are attempting to write to the local `Actionx` sheet, which has no column "A" in it (unless you added it separately).